# Abstract Use Case in Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, abstract, use-case, enterprise-architect

How do I create an abstract use case in enterprise architect 10?

**Edit:**

Here is an example:

[image]

How do I achieve this in Enterprise Architect?

Stereotyping the use case as "abstract" does not change the font face.

I'm not asking how to change the font manually. I was expecting that if a use case is stereotyped as "abstract" then its title font face would automatically be changed to italic. But that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the properties window (not the dialog that pops up when you double click on the element, the windows default posion is in the lower-left corner).
2. In the "Advanced" section set "Abstract" to "True".

[image]

Comment: RTFM we had discussed yesterday would work as well, see http://www.sparxsystems.eu/resources/project-development-with-uml-and-ea/use-case-diagram/ chapter "Specialization (Generalization)", footnote "[1] select the element and within the window Properties set Abstract to True in the section Advanced"

Comment: I've updated my answer with this solution, which is much better than what I originally proposed. Since mine has some background information and a (still valid) alternative solution for scripting I won't delete it but I think you should mark this one as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Uffe Thanks again, your original answer has pointed me to this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the type of element, "abstractness" is not expressed as a stereotype in EA, so that wouldn't work for classes either. Instead, there is an "abstract" checkbox in the element's Properties dialog. You'll find it on the Details page if you open the dialog for a class.

The same dialog for a use case, however, does not include the "abstract" checkbox. However, the underlying data model allows any element to be abstract, including use cases.

Leaving aside the correctness or otherwise of modelling abstract use cases in favor of answering the actual question, there are two ways to achieve an abstract use case in EA. Both are "proper" in that they result in use cases with the appropriate "abstract" property set, as opposed to making purely cosmetic changes in the font or similar.

Use cases made abstract in either of these ways will be displayed with an italic font automatically, they can be distinguished in searches and generated reports, etc.

**Method 1: element properties window**

In the Element Properties Window (not the dialog but the one you open in Element menu), you can set the "abstract" property under the Advanced branch.

[image: Properties window]

**Method 2: use a script**

Here's a VB script snippet which makes a single use case abstract.

```
if (theElement.Type = "UseCase") then
    theElement.Abstract = 1
    theElement.Update()
end if
```

If you place that in a diagram or object browser script you can easily make a use case abstract. You'll probably want to modify it to make it a toggle rather than one-way, but you get the idea.

This can be useful if you've already created a number of concrete use cases and want to make them abstract.

Answer (score 1):

### It is possible, but useless, and and style both in UML and OOP

If your client insists on the structure, you can show variations of some behaviour by *extends* and *include* stereotypes. And some of the variations can have a note that says, that this variation will be never really realized. This is semantically equivalent to your abstract use case. ...And the uselessness of the thing is obvious, too.

You can set Abstrect property directly, as is shown in a neighbouring answer. But it doesn't add to usefullness.

More reasons not to use "abstract" :

- What does being abstract means? It means, that this very structure will be never realized by itself, and will only provide some common features to other, concrete structures. I.e., it is setting the way of REALIZATION, the inner construction of your system. And you should NOT solve problems of realization on UC diagrams, they are merely formal way of setting the task you are solving. You should not mix setting the task and solving it.
- In technical way, being abstract is a structural piece of information. Use case diagram is a behavioral diagram. You CAN use structural elements borrowed from other diagrams in it, though. For example, abstract classes. But it is for exceptional use, not standard one. For example, you are solving the task and (*alas!*) you have already some SW/HW rigidly set due to licenses or politics. It is not good, but it can happen. But use case itself if pure behavioral element and you can't simply say it is abstract.
- "abstract" is a word used in some languages, but not in all OOP languages. You shouldn't set the language in the UC diagram.
- Use case shows behaviour, and will be realized first rather by interface than by class. And all interfaces already are abstract.

Comment: *"I.e., it is setting the way of REALIZATION, the inner construction of your system"* - the same argument can be used against <<include>>ing non-abstract UCs. Whether or not the UC can be used as standalone isn't relevant, it's just a means of breaking down the larger UC to a smaller logical blocks. Any breakdown to lower level blocks poses some constraints on the realization.

Comment: 1. Includes and Extends are merely means for abbreviation. With them you needn't repeat the same info on many places. But I don't like them, too, for they can express realization. 2. "Whether or not the UC can be used as standalone..." - Have I written a word about it? And sorry, I don't understand the sentence at all. 3. "Any breakdown to lower level blocks poses some constraints on the realization" - Surely, it is a very bad style. But be careful, friend! Who said what is lower level? You can make a class diagram for the highest level, setting the structure of the manual.

Comment: Actually, you can set language in a UC diagram, as well as on individual use cases. In my opinion it is not normally meaningful to do so (implementation language being an aspect of the realization and not of the analysis), but the functionality is there.

Comment: @Uffe Of course, you can really. It is "merely" extremely bad style. Thank you for correction.

Comment: Whether abstract use cases are meaningful is an aspect of the method being used, it is not a universal constant in the documentation language (UML). One use case (!) for abstract use cases could be to describe patterns which should be followed in implementations but are not directly realized by any component; in EA you could exclude such abstract use cases from a model validation which flags unrealized use cases. Yes, the same effect can be achieved using stereotypes or tagged values, but the point is that the concept of an abstract use case is not necessarily invalid.

Comment: @Gangnus 2. You're making an emphasis on the abstractness of UC and reasons why it's bad - I'm opposing this claim by showing that your arguments aren't exclusive to abstract UCs thus they can't be used to demonstrate that abstract UC is bad compared to non-abstract one. 3. Exactly. And abstract UC is no different in this context from other means of breaking down to lower level items. There are occasions for which this can be justified and beneficial and there are others for which it can't - it's all very dependent on the actual problem to be solved.